# setContentView of multiple activities from a another class

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

I am creating a android application which needs to be able to setcontentview on  multiple android activities layouts in few methods in a another global class. Therefore when I call the method from a new activity onCreate then the buttons and textviews are assigned by findviewbyId by method in previously defined class. Example code is shown below.

```
   public void executeWorkItem() {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
            button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText textPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNum);
                    EditText textSms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.smsContent);
                    final String phoneNumber = textPhone.getText().toString();
                    final String message = textSms.getText().toString();
                    Map<String, Object> results = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    results.put("phoneNmbr", "" + phoneNumber);
                    results.put("message", "" + message);
                }
            });
        }
```

Therefore when I call this method from activity like shown below then the methhod should be executed without getting null error.

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    app = (MyApplication)getApplication();

     // Call a custom application method
    app.executeWorkItem();
}
```

Therefore should I create a application class for this or do I have to create a Object which extends Activity and call that object method in there ?
Note : that I should be able to create different methods which can do similar things.

Comment: Why are you using the same layout and views for a bunch of activities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very easy to do. All you need is a Parent Activity like a BaseActivity, then all the other activities simple extend that Parent Activity, like so:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText textPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNum);
                EditText textSms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.smsContent);
                final String phoneNumber = textPhone.getText().toString();
                final String message = textSms.getText().toString();
                Map<String, Object> results = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                results.put("phoneNmbr", "" + phoneNumber);
                results.put("message", "" + message);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then all your other activities extend the Parent Activity like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Do not call setContentView again
    }
}

public class SecondActivity extends BaseActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Do not call setContentView again
    }
}
```

If you notice the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` It is simply calling the onCreate method of it's parent class, in this case BaseActivity (which in turn calls Activity class).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I am getting your question fully correct, but perhaps you should create base class for your activities that would wire all common listeners and other things on its `onCreate()`. Your layouts should contain all the buttons base class expects to find (most likely you may want to use `<include>` or `<merge>` ([see docs](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)). Alternatively you can consider using `Fragments` but that may be more work for you to do.

PS: I do not know what `app.executeWorkItem();` is doing but are you sure application class is the right place for it?

**EDIT**

> I am not sure about that. I want to handle multiple layouts of multiple activities from single class / activity

This is only matter of how you pass the layoutId to be used. You can make base class abstract with method like `abstract int getLayoutId())` and then your base's `onCreate()` would only need to do `setContentView(getLayoutId());` or you can drop base's `onCreate()` and instead override `setContentView())` and do your wiring there (but I do not like that really).

Comment: I am not sure about that. I want to handle multiple layouts of multiple activities from single class / activity

Comment: See edited answer. Accepted answer makes each activity use the same layout so what's the point of having different activities then?